# how to receive json values on API call in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an API with a HttpPost function, but when I call the API from JavaScript, the method variables are always 0. I use [FromBody], is this right?

Function:

```
[HttpPost("API/AddToCart")]
public async Task AddToCartAsync([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] int count)
```

The json I pass to the function:

```
{ "id": id, "count": count }
```

The function gets called but without the supplied values.
Everything works if I use HttpGet and passes the data as query.

Any tips ?

Comment: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody) - _” When a parameter has [FromBody], …  at most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. So this will not work:”_ . Try defining a simple object with the two properties and read that from the body.

Answer (score 3):

Created a model to receive the values.

Model:

```
public class AddToCartModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
public async Task AddToCartAsync([FromBody] AddToCartModel data)
```